# MongoDB nested array count implementation in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with the below structure

```
_id:"123"
dealnum:"332"
contact: {
  Phones: {
    Home:123
    Work:332
  }
}
```

How do I count the number of elements under Phone.I need to implement this in Java. Phone is an array with 2 elements. I have used unwind, project and still don't see the right results.

Comment: The way you had posted, `Phones` field is _not_ an array - its a sub-document (or embedded document). An array is defined with elements enclosed in _square brackets_ (`[ 1, 34, 27 ]`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If it's maven project use below dependency and create

```
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> 

   <artifactId>gson</artifactId> 

   <version>2.6.2</version>
```

Create java object representing above json

And json to java conversation can be as

Gson gson = new Gson();

```
    // Converting json to object 

    // first parameter should be prpreocessed json 

    // and second should be mapping class 

    Organisation organisation 

        = gson.fromJson(OrganisationJson, 

                        Organisation.class);
```